# CrossDomain Access, HLS through CloudFront with Signed URL(JWplayer)

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I am using **HLS** streaming with the **Amazon S3** and **Cloud Front** using the **JWplayer**.**(With Rails)**

I used the Signed URL to encrypt the URL and created an Origin Access Identity as given in the Amazon Cloud Front documentation. 
The Signed URL's are generated fine.

I also have a **'crossdomain.xml'** file in my bucket which is allowing all the origins(I have given '*')
Now, when I am trying to play my Hls video files from my bucket, I am getting **crossdomain access denied issue**

I think JW Player is trying to access the 'crossdomain.xml' file without the signed hash. So, it's getting that error.

I have tested my file in demo JWplayer Stream tester and this is the error I am getting in console.

```
Fetch API cannot load http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/xxx/1/1m_test.ts.
```

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
`Origin 'http://demo.jwplayer.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403.`

`If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

[image: Here is the ScreenShot.]

Here is the ScreenShot.

Please help me out. Thank You.

[This is the link I followed to configure my CloudFront Distribution](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE22EWFR4H86/Accessing-Private-Content-in-Amazon-CloudFront)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem (but with the Flowplayer). I am not sure yet about security risks (and if all steps are needed), but I got it running with:

- adding permissions on the crossdomain.xml for everyone to open/download
- adding a behaviour in the cloudfront distribution only for crossdomain.xml without restricting access (above the behaviour for * with restricted access)
- and then I noticed that in the bucket, the link to the crossdomain.xml was something like "https://some-server.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/%1Fcrossdomain.xml" (notice the weird %1F) and that when I went on rename of the crossdomain.xml, I could delete one invisible character on first position of the name (I didn't make the crossdomain.xml, so I am not sure how this happened)

Edit:
I had hlsjs also running with this and making the crossdomain.xml accessible somehow disabled the CORS request. I am still looking into this.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Just the first and second bullets are required. I've also tested this in Flowplayer.